# Pass data returned by eloquent Model::find() to DomPDF data array

Tags: laravel, eloquent, dompdf, laravel-9

The problem to solve:

In the front end, the user selects several posts from a list and press a button to export this selection of posts to pdf (send the ids of these posts in the axios request).

On the server side, the posts corresponding to these ids are retrieved with `$posts = Post::find($payload);`

It follows the whole process of creating the pdf with DomPDF and blade.

The problem to solve, specifically, is sending the $posts to the blade file.

Front End Vue/Quasar

```
posts: [
    0 : {id: 1, name: 'Post one'}
    1 : {id: 2, name: 'Post two'}
]

let payload = posts.map((obj) => obj.id);

this.$axios
    .post(`pdf_posts`, payload)
    .then((response) => {
        window.open(response.request.responseURL);
    })
    .catch((error) => {});
```

pdf_posts.blade.php

```
{{-- Comment: Just to check; returns [] --}}
<div> {{ $posts'] }}</div>

@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <div> {{ $post['name'] }}</div>
@endforeach
```

Laravel controller

```
public function generatePostsPdf(Request $request)
{
    $payload = $request->all();
    $posts = Post::find($payload);

    /*
    return response()->json(["posts" => $posts]);
    //return posts
    posts: [
         0 : {id: 1, name: 'Post one'}
         1 : {id: 2, name: 'Post two'}
    ]
    */

    $data = [
      'posts' => $posts, // in pdf_posts.blade.php file returns []
    ];

    $pdf = Pdf::loadView('pdf_posts', $data);
    return $pdf->stream("pdf_posts.pdf");
}
```

In this specific case, how to correctly pass `$posts` to `$data = [ 'posts' => $posts ];`

EDITED

The problem may be in the output format of the data returned in $payload and passed to the find() method.

If `$payload = $request->all();` is replaced with `$payload = [1, 2]` works fine;

Comment: You should use ```$data['posts']``` instead of ```$posts``` in ```@foreach```. Try with ```$pdf = Pdf::loadView('pdf_posts', compact('posts'));```

Comment: thanks. Your suggestion did not work in my case. compact() might be a way to go. I will keep trying. I edited my post.

Comment: what is the output of `dd($request->all() );`

Comment: Thanks Silver. I was just doing a series of tests to verify that. The array is empty. Apparently with DomPDF only GET requests work. The problem will be that in the response of the axios POST request the URL is returned, but the method is POST (I think it necessarily needs GET in this case). Being POST window.open(response.request.responseURL); does not work and throws the exception 'The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.' I've already tried to create a work around duplicating the same route, but with GET. Loads the pdf, but the array is empty.